# C# Invoke child form hangs application random

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, invoke, freeze, mdichild

In my windows form application I call, from the main MDIContainer form, a class in which I invoke the open of the child form.

In Main Form :

```
private void btnTemplate_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
  beiProgressBar.EditValue = "Form opening in progress...";
  repositoryItemMarqueeProgressBar1.ShowTitle = true;
  beiProgressBar.Visibility = BarItemVisibility.Always;

  bwTemplate.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bwTemplate_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  FrmTemplate frm;


  frm = new FrmTemplate();
  Callback.SetFormTemplate(this, ref frm);
}
```

In the Callback class I show the child form :

```
public delegate void SetFormTemplateCallback(FrmMain pFormMain, ref FrmTemplate pForm);

public static void SetFormTemplate(FrmMain pFormMain, ref FrmTemplate pForm)
{
  if (pFormMain.InvokeRequired)
  {
    SetFormTemplateCallback d = new SetFormTemplateCallback(SetFormTemplate);
    pFormMain.Invoke(d, new object[] { pFormMain, pForm });
  }
  else
  {
    pForm.MdiParent = pFormMain;
    pForm.InitForm();
    pForm.Show();
  }
}
```

This operation randomly hangs my application.

I also tried with BeginInvoke but the problem is still present.

I noticed that often the application freeze when it is minimized.

It is difficult also debug this error.

Anyone has ever reached a similar behavior ?

Comment: You're creating the "child" form (and consequently all its child controls) from a non-UI thread in `DoWork()`, and then creating cross-thread problems by joining the child and parent together.  Don't do that.  It creates "random" problems like you're seeing.  Why the shenanigans with the thread in the first place?

Comment: I think @idlemind's answer is correct, but I'm curious why you are passing `pForm` around by `ref` (your parameter is declared `ref FrmTemplate pForm`). I don't see you changing the value of the `pForm` variable, why the by-ref-ness?

Comment: The desired behavior should have been to open each child module in a separate thread, but I think the approach is wrong.
In any case, would it make sense to do this type of operation?